# To refine the separation of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is one data frame with three columns(model, lot_1 & class)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','A','A','A', 'A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                  'lot_1':[0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,1,1,2,2],
                  'class':['0','3','3','2','2','1','5','5','0','0','0','1','1','1']})
```

[image]

I want to divide Lot_1 according to class by model and add it to Lot_2.

The number of Lot_1 must be kept in order, and the number of class doesn't means order or size (just for distinction)

Even if it's the same lot_1 number, if the class is different, divide it in the order of Lot_1
It should be the next number

When the model changes, lot_1 starts from zero again

what I want is below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for consecutive columns by both columns and pass to [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
s = df[['lot_1','class']].ne(df[['lot_1','class']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

df['lot_2'] = s.groupby(df['model']).rank(method='dense').astype(int).sub(1)
print (df)
   model  lot_1 class  lot_2
0      A      0     0      0
1      A      0     3      1
2      A      0     3      1
3      A      0     2      2
4      A      0     2      2
5      A      1     1      3
6      A      2     5      4
7      A      2     5      4
8      B      0     0      0
9      B      0     0      0
10     B      1     0      1
11     B      1     1      2
12     B      2     1      3
13     B      2     1      3
```

Alternative solution with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = df[['lot_1','class']].ne(df[['lot_1','class']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

df['lot_2'] = s.groupby(df['model']).transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
print (df)
   model  lot_1 class  lot_2
0      A      0     0      0
1      A      0     3      1
2      A      0     3      1
3      A      0     2      2
4      A      0     2      2
5      A      1     1      3
6      A      2     5      4
7      A      2     5      4
8      B      0     0      0
9      B      0     0      0
10     B      1     0      1
11     B      1     1      2
12     B      2     1      3
13     B      2     1      3
```

Comment: did you mean `Use DataFrame.shift with DataFrame.cumsum`?